# Pivoting data to find unique values for specific columns

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table:

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | G | CA | DA | EA |
| 2 | Y | G | CA | DA | EA |
| 3 | Y | G | CA | DA | EA |
| 1 | X | Q | RA | DA | EA |
| 2 | X | Q | CA | DA | EA |

For col1 and col2, I want to create 4 additional columns. Two for the distinct values for col1 (X,Y) and two for the distinct values for col2 (G,Q).

For example, I want to create a new column (col1_x) to display 'Y' if col1 have X. Basically for each ID, col3, col4 and col5 combination - I want to show if col1 have X , col1 have Y, col2 have G and col2 have Q. Each as an individual column. How do I do that? I think I'll need a pivot/group by as I would want to eliminate duplicated rows of data.

Desired output:

| ID | col3 | col4 | col5 | col1_X | col1_Y | col2_G | col2_Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CA | DA | EA | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| 1 | RA | DA | EA | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| 2 | CA | DA | EA | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| 3 | CA | DA | EA | N | Y | Y | N |

Comment: *For example, if the ID 1 have col1 = X then I want to display 'Y' under col1_X* Why do you want to display Y here. The logic is not clear. It seems like a random decision.

Comment: I meant to create a new column (col1_x) to display 'Y' if col1 have X. Basically for each ID, col3, col4 and col5 combination - I want to show if col1 have X , col1 have Y, col2 have G and col2 have Q. Each as an individual column.

Comment: Okay I see ... I have used pivot sort of like this once but it were a long time ago

Comment: Your last comment explains better what you want and should be in the question.

Comment: For the combination: (1 CA DA EA) why the result for col1_X and col2_Q is 'Y'?

Answer (score 1):

#### Test data

```
drop table if exists #test;
drop table if exists #result;

create table #test (
    [ID] int,
    [col1] varchar(1),
    [col2] varchar(1),
    [col3] varchar(2),
    [col4] varchar(2),
    [col5] varchar(2));

insert into #test ([ID], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5]) 
values
(1, 'Y', 'G', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(2, 'Y', 'G', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(3, 'Y', 'Q', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(1, 'X', 'G', 'RA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(2, 'X', 'G', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(3, 'X', 'Q', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA');
```

#### 1) Pivot solution

Here is a pivot approach - it is not purely dynamic as you have to provide "column names" in the select which are the values you are looking for (X/Y and G/Q) - it needs to be done twice, once for each column you are interested in (col1 and col2) so it ends up looking more complex than might be hoped for, but it is is really one simple pivot, done twice, then cleaned up per your desired output. It seems like a 'trick' to me, still - after all these years!  More info on PIVOT here: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
select 
    a.ID, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5, 
    case when cast(a.[X] as bit) = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Col1_X, 
    case when cast(a.[Y] as bit) = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as col1_Y,
    case when cast(b.[G] as bit) = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as col2_G,
    case when cast(b.[Q] as bit) = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as col2_Q
from
(
    select 
        ID, col3, col4, col5, [X], [Y]
        from #test
        pivot(
            Count(col1) for [col1] in ([X], [Y])
            ) as tmp 
) a
inner join
(
    select 
        ID, col3, col4, col5, [G], [Q]
        from #test
        pivot(
            Count(col1) for [col2] in ([G], [Q])
            ) as tmp 
) b
on a.ID = b.ID
and a.col3 = b.col3
and a.col4 = b.col4
and a.col5 = b.col5
```

#### 2) Naive solution

I created a "naive" solution that I think is not really so bad and has the benefit of being understandable to anyone with a little sql skill, whereas it is a little obscure how pivot is working in a case like this (where we are not "really" aggregating information such as sums, averages, or real counts).

```
-- create the output table
select 
distinct ID, col3, col4, col5, 
    'N' as col1_X, 'N' as col1_Y, 'N' as col2_G, 'N' as col2_Q
into #result 
from #Test;

-- update the results
update t1
set t1.col1_X = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID
    and t2.col3 = t1.col3
    and t2.col4 = t1.col4
    and t2.col5 = t1.col5 
    and t2.col1 = 'X');

update t1
set t1.col1_Y = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID
    and t2.col3 = t1.col3
    and t2.col4 = t1.col4
    and t2.col5 = t1.col5
    and t2.col1 = 'Y');

update t1
set t1.col2_G = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID
    and t2.col3 = t1.col3
    and t2.col4 = t1.col4
    and t2.col5 = t1.col5
    and t2.col2 = 'G');

update t1
set t1.col2_Q = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID
    and t2.col3 = t1.col3
    and t2.col4 = t1.col4
    and t2.col5 = t1.col5 
    and t2.col2 = 'Q');

select * from #result;
```

Result in both cases:

| ID | col3 | col4 | col5 | col1_X | col1_Y | col2_G | col2_Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CA | DA | EA | N | Y | Y | N |
| 1 | RA | DA | EA | Y | N | Y | N |
| 2 | CA | DA | EA | Y | Y | Y | N |
| 3 | CA | DA | EA | Y | Y | N | Y |

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort @topsail. I tried your pivot solution however I was still getting duplicates. I think it was because the two pivots had different values for col1_x, col1_Y, col2_g and col2_Q. I tried another solution which was going back to using case for each of col1_x, col1_y, col2_g and col2_q. But instead of 'N' I used blank. Then I did a group by col3,col4,col5 and used max(col1_x), max(col1_y), max(col2_g), max(col2_q) to get my results.

Answer (score 1):

```
select col3, col4, col5,
max(col1_X),
max(col1_Y),
max(col2_G),
max(col2_Q)

from 
(select col3, col4, col5,
case when col1 = 'X' then 'Y' else 'N' end as col1_X,
case when col1 = 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end as col1_Y,
case when col2 = 'G' then 'Y' else 'N' end as col2_G,
case when col2 = 'Q' then 'Y' else 'N' end as col1_Q

From table) query

Group by col3, col4, col5
```

Comment: This is a nice idea using max()